# Regular Expression for Screen Solution

Tags: php, regex

I have following string

```
540x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2]
```

The Result I want is the

```
540x360
```

How can i do , Please suggest so that in future i will be able to solve these kind of problem my self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use a regular expression you can use:

```
$string = "540x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2]";
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^(\d+x\d+)/i', $string, &$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Nice. This is especially useful if the resolution isn't at the start, or contains spaces: `800 x 600` will explode badly, but the regex can easily be adapted to support it. I'd probably write it as `/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)/i`, to capture both numbers. In addition, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

```
$split = explode(' ', $string);
echo $split[0];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Dear down-voter, kindly explain why you down-voted me. Sincerely, karim79.

Answer (score 2):

No need to conver the string to an array, which can be quite annoying.

```
sscanf($str, "%s ", $resolution);
// $resolution = 540x360
```

This can be easily modified to get the integer values of the resolution:

```
sscanf($str, "%dx%d ", $resolution_w, $resolution_h);
// $resolution_w = 540
// $resolution_h = 360
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function extractResolution($fromString, $returnObject=false)
{
    static $regex = '~(?P<horizontal>[\d]+?)x(?P<vertical>[\d]+?)\s(?P<ignorable_garbage>.+?)$~';

    $matches = array();
    $count = preg_match($regex, $fromString, $matches);
    if ($count === 1)
    {
        /*
        print_r($matches);

        Array
        (
            [0] => 540x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2] 
            [horizontal] => 540
            [1] => 540
            [vertical] => 360
            [2] => 360
            [ignorable_garbage] => [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2] 
            [3] => [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2] 
        )
        */

        $resolution = $matches['horizontal'] . 'x' . $matches['vertical'];

        if ($returnObject)
        {
            $result = new stdClass();
            $result->horizontal = $matches['horizontal'];
            $result->vertical = $matches['vertical'];
            $result->resolution = $resolution;
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $resolution;
        }
    }
}

$test = '540x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2] ';

printf("Resolution: %s\n", var_export(extractResolution($test, true), true));
/*
Resolution: stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'horizontal' => '540',
   'vertical' => '360',
   'resolution' => '540x360',
))
*/

printf("Resolution: %s\n", var_export(extractResolution($test, false), true));
/*
Resolution: '540x360'
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $res = str_replace(explode("[", "540x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2]"), " ", "");
  echo $res[0];
```

Comment: this will be return a space after the result: "540x360 "